# Mysql 5.7.23 slows down after few hours and needs to be restarted

Tags: mysql, database-performance, mysql-5.7

3 weeks ago we migrated from Mysql 5.6.22 to 5.7.23 Using Logical Method. after that we started to get bug error which is already submitted, but now the DB started to slow down and we need to restart every 10 hours approximately.

This is reflected in a trigger on a table that receives about 700 Records per minute, when just started every record is processed in about 22ms. gradually start to take more and more time up to 300ms. when it is not enough and a bottleneck start to build, so we restart the DB and works fast again. 
The innodb buffer pool does not even gets to 15% of usage.

The trigger performs various selects and gather information to fill up the rest of the record, nothing really fancy from tables with no more than 3k records.

Any suggestions of what may be causing the issue?
Thanks in Advance

```
Hardware Specs: 
Nombre del sistema operativo:              Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Standard
Versión del sistema operativo:             6.2.9200 N/D Compilación 9200
Fabricante del sistema operativo:          Microsoft Corporation
Configuración del sistema operativo:       Servidor independiente
Tipo de compilación del sistema operativo: Multiprocessor Free

Fabricante del sistema:                    VMware, Inc.
Modelo el sistema:                         VMware Virtual Platform
Tipo de sistema:                           x64-based PC
Procesador(es):                            2 Procesadores instalados.
                                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 45 Stepping 7 GenuineIntel ~2400 Mhz
                                           [02]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 45 Stepping 7 GenuineIntel ~2400 Mhz
Versión del BIOS:                          Phoenix Technologies LTD 6.00, 22/06/2012

Cantidad total de memoria física:          49,151 MB
Memoria física disponible:                 37,501 MB
Memoria virtual: tamaño máximo:            55,551 MB
Memoria virtual: disponible:               21,520 MB
Memoria virtual: en uso:                   34,031 MB
Server Configuration:  

[mysqld]

# Storage  
basedir=e:/DB5723/
datadir=e:/DB5723/Data/
innodb_file_per_table=ON  

#Memory Resources                   
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 24G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct=75 

innodb_lru_scan_depth=1024
innodb_log_buffer_size = 128M  
innodb_log_file_size=512M

max_allowed_packet = 4M 
max_heap_table_size = 64M

join_buffer_size = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 64M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M 

query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=OFF

# Connections 
skip-name-resolve
max_connections = 151
max_connect_errors = 5
socket=e:/DB5723/tmp/mysql.sock
port=3307 
wait_timeout=600 

# Thread Setting 

        innodb_thread_concurrency=16
        innodb_read_io_threads=8
        innodb_write_io_threads=8
        thread_cache_size = 9

#Error Control / Log   
log_error_verbosity=3 
general_log_file=e:/DB5723/Data/General.log

# Security ( Brute Force Attack ) 
plugin-load-add=connection_control.dll
connection-control=FORCE_PLUS_PERMANENT
connection-control-failed-login-attempts=FORCE_PLUS_PERMANENT
connection_control_failed_connections_threshold=3
connection_control_max_connection_delay=120000
connection_control_min_connection_delay=60000


# Replication 
server_id=1
log_bin=g:/DB5723-bin
max_binlog_size=512M
binlog_format = ROW
sync_binlog=1


# Miscelaneous 
character-set-server=utf8 
event_scheduler = ON
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=ON
innodb_checksum_algorithm=crc32
innodb_checksums=ON   

sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

# I/O Hdd Performance Settings  
innodb_io_capacity=800
innodb_io_capacity_max=1000
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
```

Comment: There are 6 suggestions, posted Nov 13, 2018 waiting for you to view and consider applying.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix *might* be to change to

```
sync_binlog = 0
```

For more discussion, please provide the query that fires the trigger, the trigger definition, `CREATE TABLE`, and `Max_used_connections`.

Also, what type of disk is involved (HDD vs SSD)?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your my.ini [mysqld] section

Rate Per Second=RPS

```
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 see refman to reduce CPU load every SECOND
sort_buffer_size=2M  # from 64M  a per connection RAM request and 64M is TOO MUCH
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K  # from 16M to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS
thread_cache_size=48  # from 9 to reduce threads_created count
innodb_io_capacity_max=2000  # from 1000 for default max
innodb_io_capacity=1600  # from 800 to allow more IOPS to your HDD
```

for additional suggestions, view my profile, Network profile for contact info, please.